A matter of environmental temperature
Why is it that at 25°C indoors and approximately 32°C outside, you feel cold indoors, while in winter when it's 10°C outside, and at 25°C indoors you're bursting with heat?

hm interesting is this really a case? well probably when its cold outside u have some sort of heating on indoors which is radiating much more then 25C and vice versa when air conditioning is on to maintain that 25C in a house maybe that causes us to feel warm; also when u enter from colder environment into the warmer one it feels hotter while when entering from hotter to colder it feels colder until body adapts

Also wearing the exact same clothing on those conditions is rare.

I repeat to be clearer: I have been in my office for a few hours and I have the air conditioning on, my weather station placed about 5 meters from the air conditioning measures 35.2 °C outside and 26 °C inside and I have the sensation of coolness. In winter when outside we have for example 10 °C and inside the same temperature that I have here now, without entering or exiting, that is, being in my office for a long time, I would feel very hot and would have to reduce the temperature to twenty degrees to have a comfortable and not suffocating environment. Why then are the sensations different?

If my question is stupid I'll delete it immediately without wasting time.

The thermal conductivity of humid air is higher than that of the dry and winter air is dry; the sensation of feeling cold or hot is related to the rate of heat loss to the environment you suffer.
